# Is there any procedure on macOS systems to manually set a network interface to a self-assigned address?

Tags: network

I develop a network related application that interacts with network settings at system level. I experience a rare issue while using my app, my macOS system loses internet connectivity completely and I get in System Preferences a "Self-Assigned" IP for my network interface. In order to make my app detect and hopefully solve this issue, I would like to simulate this condition. Is there any expert that could bring me in the right direction ? Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Hi @AlfonsoTesauro - have your tried unplugging the network - that generally causes Self-Assigned?

Answer (score 1):

macOS self assigns an ip if the network adapter is working properly, but it can't communicate with a DHCP Server.

So you could connect your Mac to another Computer (with no DHCP Server running) with an Ethernet cable or stop the DHCP-Server on your router from running to get this effect.

> Note: If you disable the DHCP Server in your router, make sure to remember the IP and subnet of the router to be able to enable it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ant. I really appreciate your answer, but there is a problem: As stated in the question, I need to simulate this condition in a way that it "should" have an IP address but it doesn't. This is very important because after simulating the situation I have to find a way to programmatically fix it. So I need to simulate it with the DHCP server working, along with everything else but my system configuration. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro you want to tweak your system configuration to not listen to dhcp requests anymore?
You could use iptables to block the DHCP packages like this :
```
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 67 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --sport 68 -j DROP
```
This should also have the desired effect